# pdftk (or other linux package dependencies) with shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am hoping to write a shiny package that depends on an external ubuntu package/library. In this case pdftk. In the most basic case

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$text <- renderText({
      call = system2('pdftk',stdout = TRUE)
      'meh'
  })
})
```

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  textOutput("text")
))
```

Gives the log message `sh: 1: pdftk: not found` in shinyapps.io dashboard. Is there a way to request shinyapps.io server to install required linux dependencies?

Note: this has been hard to google as package and dependency tend to give me links related to R packages. If anyone has better keywords in mind I can edit the post.

Comment: Before checking on shinyapps.io dashboard, Did it work on your local machine?

Comment: My guess would be that pdftk is not accessible through `$PATH`. This can happen if your R session doesn't have all the privileges you're assuming it has.

Comment: @amrrs If I run it in a local machine, it'll give me the `SYNOPSIS pdftk...` thing that pops up. @roman, That may be the case but my guess it it's not even installed. It was installed in my ubuntu machine by default but not in the windows subsystem so I guess it's possible that it just comes without it.

Comment: shinyapps needs all the dependencies to be within the project. They clearly state in one of the FAQs that you should file an issue if you need other *operating system* packages/binaries to be available. https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/227057448-Are-there-any-limitations-to-the-packages-I-can-use-in-an-app-I-deploy-to-shinyapps-io- Every OS pkg/app extends the attack surface area of the linux systems they build so don't be sad if they reject this, especially since R has the `pdftools` package

Comment: I see, thanks. I want to fill a pdf form with this so i think it's outside the scope of `pdftools`

Comment: Since that is the official answer I can just accept it if you write it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @hrbmrstr stated, the way to add additional dependencies is to the [github repo for shiny app dependencies](https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps-package-dependencies). This repo includes code that is excecuted before a dependent package is installed. Which means whatever dependency you want to add must be required for a package or it'll never be loaded.

Based on [this pull request](https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps-package-dependencies/pull/96), the package does not have to be on CRAN but I am unsure if they'll accept every dependency for everyone's random packages.

In the case of pdftk, `animation` package already used pdftk but did not enforce it's presence. I opened [a pull request](https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps-package-dependencies/pull/111) that includes installation of pdtfk to the pre-installation code for `animation` which is now accepted. This means as long as the app uses `animation` package, pdftk will be installed in the system and can be used with either `pdtk` function of animation or by `system`/`system2`.